# http status code for failed email send

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Consider an API call that creates a user.  On success, the user is created and a confirmation email is sent.  The response status code is 201.

If the user is not created, the response status code is 422.

What should the response status code be if user is created BUT sending the confirmation email failed?

Comment: Why wouldn't that also be a 422? It seems to make sense since the complete action could not be completed. Your other option is to move the bar for completion back to just creating the user, and leaving the confirmation email as a optional action. In that case, send a 200 with some additional info about whether the email was sent or not.

Comment: The core of the problem lies in mixing a RESTful resource creation and an RPC-style action.  The creation of the user, in a RESTful world, would be the atomic operation and return 201 or 422 (or whatever error code you choose).  Then the sending of the confirmation email might be another POST to /api/user/confirmationemailtask that then spins off the email process.  When you combine the two you find the areas of ambiguity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core of the problem lies in mixing a RESTful resource creation and an RPC-style action. The creation of the user, in a RESTful world, would be the atomic operation and return 201 or 422 (or whatever error code you choose). Then the sending of the confirmation email might be another POST to /api/user/confirmationemailtask that then spins off the email process. When you combine the two you find the areas of ambiguity.

(moved comment to answer for posterity)

Comment: But if the sending of the confirmation email is another POST to /api/user/confirmationemailtask that then spins off the email process, shouldn't it still return something to the person who make the POST request? And shouldn't that something still have https status code returned too? What should that code be?

Comment: The original create user POST should return the id of the newly created user (or an http endpoint with the link) in the body payload (assuming success with 201).  Optionally it could also return the id of any jobs associated with user creation (e.g. send email, provision database, etc).  The client can then query each job id for status or query the main user endpoint and perhaps get the list of jobs and associated status for each.  There are many options for design.