# HTTP status code when sending email failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, http

Note: I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715604/http-status-code-for-failed-email-send) but I still don't know how to go about building the sending email function correctly, so I ask this question. I need to know the HTTP status code to use when email sending succeed/failed, or if that's not the right thing to do, the right thing to do.

A POST request to my rails app will send an email.

If the email sending failed, what HTTP status code should I return to the person who send the POST request in my JSON response?

```
  def inform
    delivered = true
    begin
      UserMailer.new_comment(current_user, other_user, @note).deliver_now
    rescue Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError
      delivered = false
    end

    if delivered
      # I use :created here because email is created
      render json: { delivered: true }.to_json, status: :created
    else
      # I use :service_unavailable here because email sending failed
      render json: { delivered: false }.to_json, status: :service_unavailable
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is this an API? You may not need to return a body. If the response is not 2xx (i.e. 4xx or 5xx) then the email would not be delivered.

Comment: @BSeven My "inform" method is an API that I am going to call from my rails's JavaScript. Also, you said " If the response is not 2xx ", what do you mean by "the response" here? Do you mean the response of the "inform" method I wrote? Or do you mean the response from the email delivery from the Mailer? Are you saying that I can just return any 4xx or 5xx code as my http response status code in the "inform" method?

Comment: I meant the response from the inform action. The Mailer does not return a response code. I am saying you can return just 202 (better than 201 in this case IMHO) or 503. You don't need to return `{ delivered:` in the body. The status code has all the info in the response.

Comment: @BSeven I see, that's an excellent point! Is there a reason why you choose 503 over 502? You recommended 502 in the answer below. And why is 202 better than 201?

Comment: Haha, you're right. I meant 502. 202 is better because 201 is when a resource is created. 202 is when "the request has been received but not yet acted upon". This is exactly the case for sending mail. You have made the request, but don't know if it will succeed. For example, it would not succeed if the email is invalid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

Comment: @BSeven I see, thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

502 - `bad_gateway`

Typically used for upstream server failure.

Here's some more info: https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/502-bad-gateway-error

> a 502 Bad Gateway Error means that a server that is upstream to one that you (the client) are connecting to has run into trouble. In this scenario, this means that the server providing the 502 Bad Gateway Error is acting as a gateway

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use code 424 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.4

> The 424 (Failed Dependency) status code means that the method could
> not be performed on the resource because the requested action
> depended on another action and that action failed.  For example, if a
> command in a PROPPATCH method fails, then, at minimum, the rest of
> the commands will also fail with 424 (Failed Dependency).